# Elm Maybe.withDefault

Tags: elm

I need to unwrap a Maybe -value in one of my update functions:

```
update msg model =

  case msg of

    UpdateMainContent val ->
      Maybe.withDefault 100 (Just 42)
      model
```

This of course is dummy code and the

```
 Maybe.withDefault 100 (Just 42)
```

is taken straight out of the [documentation for Maybe](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.4/Maybe#withDefault) and not supposed to actually do anything. The compiler is complaining and saying:

```
Detected errors in 1 module.


-- TYPE MISMATCH ----------------------------------- ./src/Review/Form/State.elm

The 1st argument to function `withDefault` is causing a mismatch.

15|>             Maybe.withDefault 100 (Just 42))
16|             -- Maybe.withDefault 100 (model.activeItem)
17|             model

Function `withDefault` is expecting the 1st argument to be:

    a -> b

But it is:

    number
```

Why is it saying that "withDefault" is expecting the first argument to be

```
a -> b
```

when it is defined as

```
a -> Maybe a -> a
```

in the documentation?

Comment: Looks like you have some weird syntax error in your code and compiler fails to recognize it. Try wrapping `(Maybe.withDefault 100 (Just 42))` or adding more code it to your example.

Comment: @halfzebra that gives exactly the same error. I don't want to paste the full code path since it's big, nested and modular and that would make the question a bit to specific. However I can say that "val" is just a simple string coming in. So what you are saying is that I can have a syntax error outside of the code above that causes the error? Ill try to clarify my question a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You accidentally left in `model`:

```
UpdateMainContent val ->
  Maybe.withDefault 100 (Just 42)
  model --  <-- here
```

This makes the type inference algorithm think that `Maybe.withDefault 100 (Just 42)` should evaluate to a function that can take this `model` argument. For that to make sense, it expects `100` and `42` to be functions, but they aren't, and so it tells you.

It might help to see an example where this works:

```
f : Int -> Int
f x = x + 1

Maybe.withDefault identity (Just f) 0
```

This will evaluate to 1.

Comment: Thank you Sören! How can I rewrite it to avoid this? Just wrapping it in parens : (Maybe.withDefault 100 (Just 42)) gives the same error!

Comment: Delete the line with `model`?

Comment: I need the case to return "model". I think I am missing something here (pretty new to functional programming). Isn't it possible to execute some arbitrary code before returning something from a case?

Comment: You want the `Maybe.withDefault ...` to somehow result in the model that should be returned. (Maybe this line of questions is better suited for the elm-slack, [#help](https://elm.slack.com/messages/help) or [#beginners](https://elm.slack.com/messages/beginners)?)

Comment: PS. If you think this answer is helpful, consider accepting it so that others can see it's helpful (and so I get the oh-so-gratifying little green +15 ;).

Comment: you don't need to 'return model' but to return an updated model. If you provide the code for your model we can provide a better answer

Comment: If you want to first so some calculations before returning something (an updated model), you can use the `let ...(calculations here)... in ...(your return value here)` construct of Elm.

Comment: I suppose the let statement behaviour was what I was looking for!